# Wp super cache causes database crash

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a serious problem :

- I have a dedicaded server. I did a reboot 4h before and now i have database errors :

The home is okay : http://worldissmall.fr/
wp admin : http://worldissmall.fr/blog/wp-admin/ (database problem)
somes pages (exemple tag) : worldissmall.fr/tag/ipad-mini/ (database connection problem)

And pages are working : worldissmall.fr/2013/02/04/jailbreak-ios-6-1-untethered-tutoriel/#.URGkCb92Th4

I suppose this problem is caused by **wp-super-cache** that was desactived before the reboot (not juste before).

I tried : wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/other_notes/ without success (when i do this, all pages are telling there is database connection problem.

Does anyone have an idea ? I'm on this problem since 5 hours...

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Set
`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`
in wp-config.php , also check this file. I think something is wrong with your wp-config.php file

Comment: Done, i have : Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/www/wis/blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1141

Answer (score 0):

WP Super Cache is not crashing your database.  When you get can't connect errors it is because your MySQL server is overloaded and has no more available open connections, has used up all your memory, or is maxing out cpu.  This could be from poorly written theme or plugin code or just lots of traffic.

You can run mysqltuner to get recommended actions to take with your my.cnf configuration.  It's a pearl script executed from the command line.

Run these from the command line
`wget https://raw.github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl`

`chmod +x mysqltuner.pl`

`./mysqltuner.pl`